# Error when loading app

Tags: java, android

I am new to java. I have created a listview and named my package as AndroidList and tried to see how it works on the emulator but it brings out the error "Unfortunately Androidlist has stopped".

Here is the .java code

```
package com.exercise.androidlist;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class AndroidList extends ListActivity {

 String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
   "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
 };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DayOfWeek));
    }
}
```

And here is the logcat

```
    02-13 21:24:02.330: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-13 21:24:02.330: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-13 21:24:02.390: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-13 21:24:02.390: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-13 21:24:02.500: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-13 21:24:02.531: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-13 21:24:02.531: I/Choreographer(409): Skipped 35 frames! The application may be      doing too much work on its main thread.
    02-13 21:24:02.600: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-13 21:24:02.600: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-13 21:24:02.693: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-13 21:24:02.693: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-13 21:24:02.720: I/Choreographer(409): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

   02-13 21:24:02.812: E/StrictMode(628): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service    com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cda940 that was originally bound here
02-13 21:24:02.812: E/StrictMode(628):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-13 21:24:02.812: E/StrictMode(628):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-13 21:24:02.812: E/StrictMode(628):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-13 21:24:02.812: E/StrictMode(628):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-13 21:24:02.812: E/StrictMode(628):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-13 21:24:02.812: E/StrictMode(628):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-13 21:24:02.812: E/StrictMode(628):  at 
02-13 21:24:05.291: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-13 21:24:05.291: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-13 21:24:05.380: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-13 21:24:05.380: W/Trace(409): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-13 21:24:05.411: I/Choreographer(409): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 1):

`setContentView(R.layout.main);` is extremely important to load the layout of your activity =P

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DayOfWeek));
    }
```

and the message of your `LogCat` doesn´t have nothing relevant to find the cause, look for the word "Exception" :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the app doesn't load any view?
Uncomment `//setContentView(R.layout.main);` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

When creating `Listview` with `ListActivity` then two things are MUST     contain a `ListView` with the `android:id` attribute set to   @android:id/list    (NOT android:id="@+id/list" ).

if you will defined `ListView` with the `android:id` attribute set to
@+id/list then it will give error.

```
            public class AndroidList extends ListActivity {

             String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
               "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
             };

                /** Called when the activity is first created. */
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);

                // Define a new Adapter
                    // First parameter - Context
                    // Second parameter - Layout for the row
                    // Third - the Array of data

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DayOfWeek);
                    // Assign adapter to List
                    setListAdapter(adapter); 
                }
            }
```

Adapters are used to provide the data to the `ListView`
Parameters:
           `simple_list_item_1` :  Android internal layout view
           `values`             :  User defined data array.

```
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DayOfWeek);

         // Assign adapter to List
           setListAdapter(adapter);
```